# Can't get data- attributes from SLDS React button click

Tags: html, slds, react

According to the documentation on the React SLDS Button:

> Although not listed in the prop table, all aria-*, data-* and form* props will be added to the button element if passed in.

So my button:

```
<Button
    className="slds-button_neutral"
    data-value="test"
    label="My Button"
    onClick={handleClick}
>
</Button>
```

And my handler:

```
const handleParentSelect = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-value'));
};
```

`event.target.attributes` does NOT contain `data-value` at all (I did actually try typing the click event as well with no luck). The documentation says this should work, but it doesn't. Am I missing a piece here? Or is documentation just wrong?

Answer (score 1):

data-* attributes are generally available on the `dataset` property.

Please try `event.target.dataset.value` or `event.currentTarget.dataset.value`

Comment: Also, [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Comment: Hmmm still getting undefined with that. The button ends up looking like this: `<button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" type="button">My Button</button>` Which I think is the problem. That data attribute is not getting passed back to the button like the documentation says it should be.

Comment: Could be because `value` is a keyword. Try renaming the attribute to `data-val`, and then use `event.target.dataset.val`

Comment: `data-val` didn't work either. I am not sure if typescript is messing with the event somehow?

Comment: Hmm. I havent worked with React before, but here is a link I found on Google. https://newbedev.com/react-typescript-get-data-attribute-from-click-event `currentTarget` seems to be different from `target`.. Please try that instead.

Comment: Unfortunately still null. The button only has class and type attributes. It just isn't getting the data attributes at all.

Comment: So `aria-*` attributes show up in the attribute list and I can access them. So `aria-valuenow` works I guess for my use case... But really not sure why `data-` attributes are not working when documentation says they are.

Comment: Yep, that is strange. Ideally dataset or getAttribute shouldve worked. Hmm.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I guess I'll just go with `aria-valuenow` for now. Probably not the best way to utilize aria attributes, but if that is all that is going to work... haha

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you probably have children inside the button. In this case JS handles click event on one of the children.

https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Generally it should work with `event.currentTarget.dataset.value`. But anyway there are at least 2 more solutions:

**1) JS**

```
const handleClick = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
  let target = nativeEvent.target as HTMLElement;
  while (target.className !== 'slds-button_neutral') {
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
  const value = target.dataset.value;
  ...
}
```

**2) CSS**

```
.slds-button_neutral * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```